# Not able to find the constraints option in the Rigidbody component

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I am working on a game tutorial right now and I need to freeze constraints for a model prefab. I add a `Rigidbody` component and I want to freeze rotations on the x and z axes. However, I am not able to find the option in the component. Is there another way to access rotation constraints (I do not want to code the constraints at the moment)? Or is there something I am missing in the new version. Please do let me know. Thanks

[image: Rigidbody component. It does not have the constraints option here at all!]

I am using Unity 5.6.7f1 Personal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inspector is in Debug mode.

Click the three-dot ⋮ icon in the top-right of the Inspector tab, next to the lock icon, and select "Normal"

[image: Debug Inspector]

[image: Normal Inspector]

The constraints section then appears as a fold-out near the bottom.

Comment: Oh Thanks @DMGregory. Will check that out